# Reset your weapons for a specific new play

Tags: xbox-360, battleblock-theater

I already played this game, and now I have all the weapons and a lot of heads. Sometimes I want to play the history again with a new friend, but I want to keep the fun and mechanics of the first time, so having to play the levels one by one to unlock the next one and having to unlock weapons progressively.

On the other hand, I don't want to lose all my progress. Is that possible?

Comment: PC? Xbox? or PS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Battleblock Theatre* doesn't have a legacy mode that will give you what you're looking for.  Unfortunately, you'll need to either wipe your data completely, or just play with everything already unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe clearing your system cache should do the trick. But be warned! This will delete all progress for any achievements you have been working towards! (I had to complete the L4D "Zombie Genocidist" almost twice over because of this...)

Comment: Ok, with this I can play with nothing. How to play with the friends I played the history first, having all my weapons? I have to get again every weapon and head?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to "re-unlock" all the collectibles without losing your progress sorry, at least not on console anyway.